# Create binary matrix in Matlab reporting increasing number of ones

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I would like your advise to write a Matlab code that creates a binary matrix `A` of size `31x5` such that

- the first row of `A` is `[1 1 1 1 1]`
- from the 2nd to the 6th of `A` we have `1` only once per row

  ```
  [1 0 0 0 0
   0 1 0 0 0
   0 0 1 0 0
   0 0 0 1 0
   0 0 0 0 1]
  ```
- from the 7th to the 16th row we have `1` twice per row

  ```
  [1 1 0 0 0
   1 0 1 0 0
   1 0 0 1 0
   ...]
  ```
- from the 17th to the 26th row we have `1` three times per row
- from the 26th to the 31th row we have `1` four times per row

I could that manually, but I would like to know if there is a faster way to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach:

1. Generate all possible rows containing zeros and ones, except all zeros or all ones;
2. Sort rows (atomically) based on row sums, then on negated row values, to produce the desired order;
3. Prepend a row of ones to build the result.

```
N = 5;
A = dec2bin(1:2^N-2)-'0'; % step 1
[~, ind] = sortrows([sum(A,2) -A]); % step 2
result = [ones(1,N); A(ind,:)]; % step 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you the command bin2dec()/dec2bin() with a for-loop.
bin2dec('10000') writes 16 and your next writes bin2dec('01000') 8
so I guess you are following some sort of pattern?

put all of your wanted numbers in an array like that:

```
clear all;
nums = [16 8 4 2 0];
mat = [];
for(a=1:1:size(nums,2))
    mBinChar = dec2bin(nums(a));
    
    for(b=1:1:length(mBinChar))
        mat(a,b) = str2double(mBinChar(1));
    end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to produce the desired result

Comment: of course only under the pretense that his numbers follow a certain pattern