# Construct Matlab matrix from Cartesian product of two vectors

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Consider two Matlab vectors `A=[1 2 3 4 5]` `B=[6 7 8 9 10]`;

I would like your advise to write a Matlab matrix `C` of size `32x5` where each row has :

- as first element `A(1)` or `B(1)`
- as second element `A(2)` or `B(2)`
- as third element `A(3)` or `B(3)`
- as fourth element `A(4)` or `B(4)`
- as fifth element `A(5)` or `B(5)`

`C` should not contain equal rows. `32` comes from `2^5`, where `5` is the length of `A` and `B`.

```
 C=[1 2 3 4 5; %all elements from A (1 row)
    6 2 3 4 5; %one element from B (5 rows)
    1 7 3 4 5; 
    1 2 8 4 5; 
    1 2 3 9 5; 
    1 2 3 4 10; 
    6 7 3 4 5; %two elements from B (10 rows)
    ... ;
    6 7 8 4 5; %three elements from B (10 rows)
    ... ;
    6 7 8 9 5; %four elements from B (5 rows)] 
    ... ;
    6 7 8 9 10; %all elements from B (1 row)]
```

I could write down `C` manually, but I would like to know if there is a faster way to build it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar approach as my answer to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63113114/2586922):

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5];
B = [6 7 8 9 10];
N = numel(A);
t = dec2bin(0:2^N-1)-'0';
[~, ind_sort] = sortrows([sum(t,2) -t]);
t = t(ind_sort, :);
AB = [A B];
ind_AB = t*N + (1:N); % or bsxfun(@plus, t*N, 1:N) in old Matlab versions
result = AB(ind_AB);
```